# Editing a custom wiki page in a Drupal website (Page saving conflicts)

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have created a wiki like editing system for my site, and I realized that having two people editing a page at the same time can lead to conflicts. So I decided to set it up so that when a user opens the editor for the page the page locks others out, and then they have thirty minutes to edit the page. Then, when the time is up or they close or save the page, it unlocks for others to edit.
I thought about using cookies, but don't know anything about using them, I also saw something about using session, but I have no idea about that either. Am I on the right track, and can you give me any hints on how to do this? (I realize this might not be the preferred method of editing a wiki, but the site is low volume and the method has its advantages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a module that does what you need:

[Content locking](http://drupal.org/project/content_lock)